# Making a SOAP query with Objective C

Tags: web-services, cocoa, cocoa-touch, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to make a query to the National Rail Enquiries system using SOAP, using Objective C.  Unfortunately, I'm not getting very far with it.  I've tried a few things, and all that happens is that I get an empty set of results back.  National Rail, unfortunately, doesn't provide any support for its system - and this is compounded by the fact that I've never used SOAP either.

The schema is here - https://realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/ldbws/wsdl.aspx

I've tried quite a few different things, including change of host, API version and so forth - but I'm fumbling around in the dark, aimlessly trying to find the right magic words - which isn't very productive.  I'm sure that I'm vaguely in the right area, and that it's just a matter of fixing the request (code below).  Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

```
soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
           "<soap:Envelope xmlns:wsdl=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/\" xmlns:tns=\"http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2012-01-13/ldb/\" xmlns:ct=\"http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2012-01-13/ldb/commontypes\" xmlns:ldbt6=\"http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2012-01-13/ldb/types\">"
           "<soap:Header>"
           "<ct:AccessToken>"
           "<ct:TokenValue>MY_TOKEN_GOES_HERE</ct:TokenValue>"
           "</ct:AccessToken>"
           "</soap:Header>"
           "<soap:Body>"
           "<ldbt6:GetDepartureBoardRequest xmlns=\"http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2012-01-13/ldb/\">"
           "<ldbt6:numRows>10</ldbt6:numRows>"
           "<ldbt6:crs>LST</ldbt6:crs>"
           "</ldbt6:GetDepartureBoardRequest>"
           "</soap:Body>"
           "</soap:Envelope>"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/LDBWS/ldb6.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];
[theRequest addValue:@"realtime.nationalrail.co.uk" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue:@"http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2012-01-13/ldb/GetDepartureBoard" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if(connection)
{
    webResponseData = [NSMutableData data] ;
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Connection is NULL");
}
```

All of which returns the error:

```
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
```

The token I'm using is the token supplied by NationalRail.  Does it need to be quoted in any manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to fix this same issue and I've come across a solution obtained from this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openraildata-talk/EoemT5xJ5K0). If you obtained your access token from OpenLDBWS signup page your token will only work with the OpenLDBWS endpoint.

If you got your token before OpenLDBWS came into existence your token will work on both, however the old API will soon be decommissioned.

```
NSString *endpoint = @"https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/ldb6.asmx";

NSString *message = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"
                     "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2014-02-20/ldb/\" xmlns:ns2=\"http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2010-11-01/ldb/commontypes\">\n"
                     " <SOAP-ENV:Header>\n"
                     "  <ns2:AccessToken>\n"
                     "   <ns2:TokenValue>ACCESS-TOKEN-HERE</ns2:TokenValue>\n"
                     "  </ns2:AccessToken>\n"
                     " </SOAP-ENV:Header>\n"
                     " <SOAP-ENV:Body>\n"
                     "  <ns1:GetDepartureBoardRequest>\n"
                     "   <ns1:crs>LST</ns1:crs>\n"
                     "   <ns1:numRows>10</ns1:numRows>\n"
                     "  </ns1:GetDepartureBoardRequest>\n"
                     " </SOAP-ENV:Body>\n"
                     "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:endpoint];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[message length]];

[request addValue:@"thalesgroup.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request addValue: @"http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2012-01-13/ldb/GetDepartureBoard" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to change there:

NSURLConnection is an asynchronous class and you'll have to implement these methods to get connection status and response data:

`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;`

You can refer to the documentation here: [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html), [NSURLConnectionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html)

Also, the URL you're using is that of the WSDL and you should issue the SOAP requests at the SOAP endpoint as provided by the WSDL, not the WSDL itself. Change the NSURL to be initialised with: `https://realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/LDBWS/ldb6.asmx`

One last thing: the last `if` block is pointless. Just be sure to handle the else case: when a connection can't be made.

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions.  Actually, I didn't put all the code in - and I tried using https://realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/LDBWS/ldb6.asmx but with no more success than in the other example.  Just a different failure.  That said, I'm very grateful for your comment because it tells me which bits of my code are on the right lines!

For clarity, I have implemented didRecieveResponse and didReceiveData - but I didn't include these in my code because I don't think that the problem lies there.  I'll update the query according to your comments.